# ns3 error: invalid conversion from ‘const ns3::TcpOption*’ to ‘ns3::TcpOption*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, mptcp

I'm compiling ns3-3.26 from https://github.com/Kashif-Nadeem/ns-3.26-MPTCP.git
but I meet a problem, I dont know how to solve it, can you give me some advices?
that's error information:
[image]
thats code:

[image]

Comment: I have resolved it, just move the files to another folder, and it suceessful, I dont know....

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved it, just move the files to another folder, and it suceessful, I dont know....